# Passport authenticate and JSON response

Tags: json, node.js, web-applications, passport.js

I'm building a webapplication in NodeJS.

Back-end in application is connected with user just via Json API. I'm trying to do login option. It's possible? How can I receive response from Passport Authenticate?

> function post_api(req, res) {
>
> ```
> res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });    
> // Check method
> if(!req.body.method)
>   res.write( JSON.stringify({
>           "status":"400",
>           "response": {
>             "status" : "error",
>             "info":  "Method not defined."
>           } 
>       }));
> else
> {
>
>     if(req.body.method == "login")
>     { 
>
>         passport.authenticate('local', {failureFlash: true, successFlash: true});  
>         // Something here but i have no idea what...
>
>         res.write( JSON.stringify({
>             "status":"200",
>             "response": {
>                 "status" : "error", // or success
>                 "info":  req.flash('error')
>             }
>         })); 
>
>     }
>     else
>       res.write( JSON.stringify({
>           "status":"404",
>           "response": {
>             "status" : "error",
>             "info":  "Method not found."
>           } 
>       }));
>
> }    
> res.end(); };
> ```

This of course doesn't works, how it should look like?

Comment: this link might help you,it saved my day
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382296/how-to-send-json-as-a-response-after-passport-authenticationin-node-js/24383272#24383272