# how to send json as a response after passport authenticationin node.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport-facebook, passport-local

I am trying this [git example](https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-express-passport-mysql/blob/master/config/passport.js).

Which works well when I integrated it with my project, but what I want to achieve is to send json as a response to the client/request, instead of successRedirect : '/profile' & failureRedirect : '/signup'.

Is it possible to send a json, or is there some other methods to get the same?

Any help will be appreciated,TU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here I modified my code to send json as a response

```
// process the signup form
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/successjson', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/failurejson', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));

app.get('/successjson', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.htm');
});

app.get('/failurejson', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hello' });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use passport's authenticate function as route middleware in your express application.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    // Then you can send your json as response.
    res.json({message:"Success", username: req.user.username});
  });
```

By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401 Unauthorized status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked. If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the `req.user` property will be set to the authenticated user.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution here IMO.

Answer (score 4):

There is an official **Custom Callback** documentation:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

https://github.com/passport/www.passportjs.org/blob/master/views/docs/authenticate.md

Answer (score 3):

Create new route, e.g.: `/jsonSend` with `res.json` in it and make `successRedirect: '/jsonSend'`. That should do it.

Comment: check my below answer

Comment: If that's what you need and it works for you then it's alright ;)

Comment: yup i just want to send json after authentication

Comment: is there a any other way to get that success/ failure authentication in the same post request

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Examples maybe?

Comment: how to add callback to the app.post('/signup',passport.authenticate('local-signup'));  method to get authentication status

Comment: Well, in the callblack you can check it with `req.isAuthenticated()`. If it returns true, than your authentication was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Use passport as a middleware.

```
router.get('/auth/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook'), 
    function(req, res){
        if (req.user) { res.send(req.user); }
        else { res.send(401); }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

```
// process the signup form
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/successjson', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/failurejson', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));

app.get('/successjson', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.htm');
});

app.get('/failurejson', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hello' });
});
```